# UIViews are displayed distorted when I set statusBar to hidden

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a bunch of `UIView`s that are displayed on a `viewController`. They are setup before I call `presentModalViewController`. The problem is that these views are displayed distorted, specifically they have an extra height of 20, which is the length of the status bar. The problem goes away if I have the `statusBar` shown or I have the `UIView`s setup after the `viewController` is shown, but I need the `UIView`s to be setup before the `viewController` is shown and I dont want the `statusBar` to be shown when my app
is running. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the Autoresize subviews property of the viewController's view to NO.